# htaccess redirect to different domain with query string containing arrays

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a url like so:

`subdomain.domain.com/level1/level2?product_ids[]=1&product_ids=2&product_names[]=Something&product_names[]=Something+Else`

I want to redirect this to a new domain and preserve the query string so it should redirect to:

`subdomain.domain2.com/level1/level2?product_ids[]=1&product_ids=2&product_names[]=Something&product_names[]=Something+Else`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^level1/level2/?$ http://subdomain2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```